Run Flutter in debug mode with google-services.json for multiple users
I am currently implementing the google_sign_in package in Flutter.
I am facing the error described here and trying to fix it by adding the hashes from my debug keystore as described in this answer.
How would this process work, if I want to work on this app in debug mode with a colleague? Since we obviously have different hashes in our debug keystores. I also have not found a way to generate multiple google-services.json files.
Thanks

I am facing the same problem
